# Apache rewrite - reroute every request except this url

Tags: apache

I'm trying to set up mod_status on my server, but it's coming up with a blank page:

```
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Location>
```

I think the problem is the re-write rule right below it:

```
    <Location />
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php [L]
        </ifmodule>
    </Location>
```

So, what I'm trying to do is add a rule that will redirect all requests except for the sever-status page. I amended the second location directive, but it's not working. The complete implementation is this:

```
    <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location />
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/server-status/$
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.php [L]
        </ifmodule>
    </Location>
```

Could someone please tell me if something is wrong with this line, or there's something else I'm missing?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/server-status/$
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

I changed this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/server-status/$
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status
```